# Need assistance to understand a piece of code in java

Tags: java

```
static long nextPowerOf2(long n)
{
    n--;
    n |= n >> 1;
    n |= n >> 2;
    n |= n >> 4;
    n |= n >> 8;
    n |= n >> 16;
    n++;
    return n;
}
```

I am reading this sample code of java in a blog. Which I am facing difficult to understand this code.Please explain what this function is performing?

Comment: Do you know every [operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in there ? This is a first thing that would help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name of the method suggests it returns the next nearest and larger than `n` number which is the power of 2.

You need to run this code yourself, add the print statements and see the intermediary results of the code execution.

If you call the method `nextPowerOf2(6)` this what will be happening inside of the method:

```
n--; // n becomes 5;
n |= n >> 1; // This is equivalent to n = n | n >> 1.
            // Bit shift >> has higher precedence than bitwise OR |.
            // This is why it becomes 7. Try it yourself and read about
            // these operators.
n |= n >> 2; // n is 7
n |= n >> 4; // n is 7
n |= n >> 8; // n is 7
n |= n >> 16; // n is 7
n++; // n is 8
return n; // return n which is equal to 8 - the next nearest to 6 power of 2.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not hard to see what the function does, Could you please explain the logic behind doing n|n<<1 and n|n<<2 .. and so on, I still cant wrap my head around it

Comment: @Oswald. The OP asked for help in understanding what the code does. If you need to understand why the algorithm works you need to spend some time on it.

Comment: @Oswald. I dig out this piece of Code after suggestions from Nurzhan this code is combination of two operators for example we passed 6 then n--; performs therefore n becomes 5. Then Binary of 5 is 101 by performing one bit right shift number becomes 10 and n is still 5 i.e. 101. Now performing bitwise OR we get 101+010=111 i.e.7. Thanks for help Nurzhan.